# Pass additional information through a 302 Redirect

Tags: html, forms, http, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a webpage `/example` with a `form` that has `action="/submit"`.  `submit` will process the data sent to the server, and return a 302 redirect back to `/example`.

I would like to have (the second) `/example` display some sort of response to the user based on what the user submits to `/submit`, such as an indication of success or failure.

Sending a 302 redirect doesn't seem to have any way to tell the client to send any additional message to `/example`, so the server is unable to determine if it should indicate success or failure when fetching `/example` for the client.

I could append the success or failure message to the 302 redirect url, i.e. redirect to `/example?message=Succeeded`, but that url will stay on the user's address bar as long as he continues to browse my `/example` page, which isn't very nice.

I could change the form to have `action="/example"`, but I have multiple forms on the `/example` page, so I would need to use hidden `<input>` elements or other means to distinguish the requests submitted by the user to `/example`.  This seems to be more of a hack than a proper solution.

What is the usual way this can be accomplished?